# How to solve collation error in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, wordpress, collation

I migrated a Microsoft SQL database to Mysql and I hat some collation problems in the rows in Mysql, I tried to change the collation but the erros still there. The data is goning to be in a Wordpress, so I tried the Database Collation Fix pluguin but doesn't work.

The table afected is wp_posts in post_title and post_content. All the characters that contain an accent or 'ñ' in Spanish are replaceed by a random character.

I already tried with *utf8_spanish_ci* and *utf8mb4_spanish_ci*.

Any suggestions?

**Microsoft SQL database collation:** *Modern_Spanish_CI_AI*

**Mysql database collation:** *UTF8 Defaul Collation*

Thanks

Comment: "some collation problems" is not a sufficiently detailed description of your issue. Not enough info here to help you accurately. However, an obvious question occurs: Can you change the collation of MySQL to the same as the MS SQL one (preferably _before_ you migrate the data to it)? Or does that break Wordpress?

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to your question to give more details. What table in WordPress? Please show its definition. *Some collation problems in some rows* is not specific enough to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you, but the collating orders in MySQL's Modern Spanish `utf8_spanish_ci` and/or `utf8mb4_spanish_ci` collations are different from those in `utf8_unicode_ci` and/or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Modern Spanish collation handles `N` and `Ñ` as separate characters, with `Ñ` coming directly after `N`. Generic latin-language collation treats them as variants of the same character. So, if you want Spanish collation -- that is, if you're dealing with lots of proper names and so forth -- you'll need to use the Spanish collation for this data.

Answer (score 0):

If `ñ` turned into `?`, you have one type of problem.
If `ñ` turned into `Ã±`, you have "Mojibake".
If `ñ` turned into `�`, it's yet another problem.

Please be more specific, since the solutions are quite different.

[Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)  provides information on the common issues.

The "Collation" is not relevant to `ñ` being replaced by a 'random character'.  Only the `CHARACTER SET` is relevant.

When you get into comparing or sorting strings, *then* the `COLLATION` becomes relevant.  I think the only difference between `..._spanish_ci` and `...spanish2_ci` is the handling of `ch` and `ll`.

Comment: Ñ and accents are turned into: ? @RickJames

Comment: `?`, `Ã‘`, `�`, respectively.  The second table in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings  gives the Mojibake mappings.

Comment: Please do `SELECT HEX(..) FROM ...` to see what is in the table.